# mysqli_query() não retorna false

Tags: php, mysqli, resultset

Iniciando no PHP, recentemente aprendi OO com PHP e tive um probleminha ao converter meu código procedural para o OO. 
Tenho uma tabela "orgao" (colunas: id, nome_orgao) com somente 1 registro. Faço a consulta através de um DAO (adorei isso):

```
class OrgaoDao{
private $conexao;

function __construct($conexao){
    $this->conexao = $conexao;
}

public function buscaOrgao($nome_orgao){
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM orgao WHERE nome_orgao = '{$nome_orgao}'";
    if($resultado=mysqli_query($this->conexao,$qry)){
        $orgao_buscado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
        $orgao = new Orgao($orgao_buscado['nome_orgao']);
        $orgao->setId($orgao_buscado['id_orgao']);
        return $orgao;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Porém quando faço uma consulta a um registro que não existe no banco...

```
require_once 'cabecalho.php';
$orgaoDao = new OrgaoDao($conexao);
if($orgao = $orgaoDao->buscaOrgao($_GET['campo_orgao'])){
    echo $orgao->getNome();
    echo " ==> Encontrado";
} else {
    echo '==>  nao encontrado';
}
```

...o mysql_query() não me retorna false, creio que retorna um mysqli_result vazio ou algo do tipo. Quando dou um var_dump($resultado) ele me retorna isso:

```
object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(3)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Observações:

- a conexão ao banco está inclusa no cabecalho.php.
- também no cabeçalho, está sendo feito o autoloading (delícia) das
  classes.
- não tenho a mínima ideia do está errado pois no modo procedural
  funcionava perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O resultado obtido com o retorno de [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php) pode ser um [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli-result.php) ou `bool (false)`. Quando o retorno é `false`, tem algum problema com a **`SQL`**, ***erro de sintaxe por exemplo***, quando o retorno e [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli-result.php) o resultado foi obtido mesmo que não tenha nenhum registro, inclusive informa se o [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli-result.php) tem registro com **`->num_rows`** se for maior do que **0** tem *registro na tabela*.

O seu código teria que ser assim:

```
public function buscaOrgao($nome_orgao)
{
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM orgao WHERE nome_orgao = '{$nome_orgao}'";
    if($resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexao,$qry))
    {
        if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) 
        {
            $orgao_buscado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
            $orgao = new Orgao($orgao_buscado['nome_orgao']);
            $orgao->setId($orgao_buscado['id_orgao']);
            return $orgao;
        }
    } 
    return false;
}
```

---

Eu resumiria o seu código dessa forma

***Classe Orgao***

```
<?php

    class Orgao {
        private $id;
        private $nome_orgao;

        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }
        public function setId($id)
        {
            $this->id = $id;
            return $this;
        }
        public function getNomeOrgao()
        {
            return $this->nome_orgao;
        }
        public function setNomeOrgao($nome_orgao)
        {
            $this->nome_orgao = $nome_orgao;
            return $this;
        }
    }
```

---

**Código:**

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','senha', 'test');

$result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM orgao');

if ($result && $result->num_rows > 0)
{
    $orgao = mysqli_fetch_object($result, Orgao::class);
    var_dump($orgao);
    //echo $orgao->getId();
    //echo $orgao->getNomeOrgao();
}
```

*Isso seria um código base, só falta mesmo colocar na classe* **DAO**.

Comment: Perfeito! Agora entendi direito, eu achava que o retorno seria false caso não encontrasse registro na tabela. Muito Obrigado, resolveu um dia inteiro de neurônios queimados.